# Tkinter Label: How do I know that the text is too long for it?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

Let me explain.
You have a label. Fixed size.
And I'd like to know if there is a way to let me know whether the text I want to display in that label is too long for it.

`len()` is not good since not all characters are of the same width.

why ? well I have another label next to it showing a << when that happens, currently solved by `len()` but thats not good.

Comment: If you use monospaced font (i.e. a font which has characters of same width) that you can easily just check how many letters (i.e. string length) is too long for the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `font_measure` to determine how many pixels are required for a particular string in a particular font on a particular screen.

```
...
text="Hello, world"
default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
width = default_font.measure(text)
height = default_font.metrics("linespace")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I made it work thanks to you:

```
from tkinter import *

self.anyfontname = font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 20, weight = "bold")
text = "hi"
print(self.anyfontname.measure(text))
...
```

Thank You !!