# How to get number of pixels does this text take up?

Tags: python, tkinter, pixel, measure

I write the program in which user can set his own text on the display, but this text can be wider than the window and he gone away from visible space. I need to know how much this text take up for relocate him below and that window adjusting to him.

```
self.text = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Hello World!", background="white", font=("", 30))
self.text.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I already try to variable set self.text.winfo_width(), and then print him, but it was fruitless. I just get tuple in response.

I don't know suitable command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Label: How do I know that the text is too long for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31599824/7432)